# How to get StringAttribute with foreach_get() method?

Tags: python

I know how to transfer data from the most Attributes with other data types to Numpy arrays with foreach_get() method. Can anyone explain how to do it with `bpy.types.StringAttribute`?

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

ATTR_NAME = "My String Attribute"

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
attribute = ob.data.attributes.new(ATTR_NAME, 'STRING', 'POINT')

array = np.zeros(len(attribute.data), dtype=str)
attribute.data.foreach_get("value", array)

print(array)
```

Here is error I get:

```
Error: Only boolean, int float and enum properties supported Error:
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "//filepath", line 11, in <module>
RuntimeError: internal error setting the array
```

Comment: I'm not sure one can yet access / modify these attributes with the API. In fact they don't seem to be supported by Geometry Nodes, so I don't really know why we can create string attributes using the interface or the API. I've read they're supposed to be supported at one point, but the problem with strings is that they can require an arbitrary amount of space to be stored so that can cause problems for optimization purposes. Happy to be proven wrong :)

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#attribute-data-types), unfortunately the string type is not supported